# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::currentPage does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

Other resource routes like `order` and `product` controller index function is working and showing index page 
but when I request for category index page laravel 5.8 says

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::currentPage does not exist view categories/index.php

Here is the routing group which all other routes are working with except categories controller for showing index page from index function and dashboard for index function

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middlware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
    Route::name('dashboard.')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('/', 'DashboardController');
        Route::resource('/products', 'ProductController'); // ->except(['create', 'index']);
        Route::resource('/categories', 'categoryController'); // ->except(['create', 'index']);
        Route::resource('/orders', 'orderController'); // ->except(['create', 'index']);
    });
});
```

they are working very well but when I configure multi authentication  and make admin auth  it starts showing these errors 
please help if anyone working on `laravel5.8`

Comment: Problem is not with routing, but with method currentPage which does not exist.

Also, you have typo. categoryController in web.php but file real name is categorycontroller

Comment: You are getting BadMethodCallException. It may cause, your form action route is incorrect or route in web.php is incorrect.

Comment: Rashed Hasan sir  i have checked my route they all are correct by php artisan route:list and searching in files

Comment: #Arturs Jerjomins  sir i have checked this typo mistake but still showing problem. and  i think it is not creating problem because in this controller there is a add catagory method which is showing page to add new catagory , this method is working very well only index method is not catching

Comment: there's problem in your blade file. share your controller index method and index blade file.

Comment: zahid bro please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You're calling [currentPage](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_currentPage) property statically from a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) instance instead of a method on a [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html) instance

Your controller must return a paginated query builder instance `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` like

```php
class categoryController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      $categories = \DB::table('categories')->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(4);
      return view('dashboard.categories.index', compact('categories'));
   }
}
```

Then in your `dashboard/categories/index` view, use the `currentPage()` as a function

```php
{{ $categories->currentPage() }}
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

#### PS: Don't just copy-paste this code, it may cause other errors as I just made my best guess to what your controller looks like

Comment: Caddy DZ thanks , please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

zahid hasan emon bro this is my controller

```
class categorycontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $data = [];
//        $data['categories'] = \DB::table('categories')->get();
        $data['categories'] = \DB::table('categories')->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(4);
        return view('dashboard.categories.index',$data);
    }
```

and this is my catagory page

```
    @section('page-subtitle','List of all categories')

@section('content')
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"></h3>
            <a href="{{route('dashboard.categories.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary">New Category</a>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                {{(($categories->currentPage() * $categories->perPage())- $categories->perPage() )+1 }}
                of {{$categories->total()}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
                @forelse($categories as $category)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="action-box">
                                <a href="{{route('dashboard.categories.edit',$category->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    <tr class="text-center warning">
                        <td colspan="3">No Record Found</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforelse
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer">
            @if(count($categories))
                <div class="pull-left">
                    {{$categories->links()}}
                </div>
            @endif

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box -->
@endsection
```

i think currentpage() method which i used for showing number of pages is making problem ,but before making multi auth is was working very well